# Query regarding regexp

Tags: regex

I am trying to do the following thing using regexp:

I am working with the following string:

```
Achaval Ferrer - Finca Mirador Mendoza 2005 South America | Argentina Malbec | 750ml
```

I want to extract the following string:

```
Achaval Ferrer - Finca Mirador Mendoza 2005 South America 750ml
```

I have tried with the following regexpr:

```
^(.*?)\|.*(\|*?).*(\d{3}[a-z]*)
```

However, it gives me the output:

```
Achaval Ferrer - Finca Mirador Mendoza 2005 South America
```

I am absolutely new to regex and would appreciate any help regarding this.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: provide  the code sample how are you trying to achieve it.

Comment: What is the programming language? What is the exact pattern for the strings? Just the first part before `|` and the last one? Isn't it a work for `Split('|')` and then `Join(" ")`?

Comment: Hi | I am using a tool called parse hub (https://www.parsehub.com/) which accepts regexp for formatting/extracting strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this regex:

```
/\s*\|.*?\|\s*/g
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cM6aQ0/1)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: @RahulLahiri:- Can you tell me how it is not working? What language you are using? FYI, regex is language dependent. I tried to put that for Javascript!

Comment: @RahulLahiri:- For Javascript, see how this regex is working: http://jsfiddle.net/oqyjerns/  Hope that helps!

Comment: @RahulLahiri:- Then click the link which I pasted in my answer. REGEX DEMO

Comment: The regex is of PHP flavour it looks like. When I use the expression (\s*\|.*?\|\s*) by just putting a bracket around your expression, it gives me the outut : " | Argentina Malbec | "

Comment: You are correct. However, if you look at the "Match Information" section, it says:   "No match groups were extracted.". When I put braces around the regex however, it returns the output as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @RahulLahiri:- Thats because there were no match groups. Your question never said to make a matched group. You asked to replace it and so does the above Regex does.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry if I was not more clear. Actually, the regex should produce the output as mentioned above rather than replacing a part of the string. Since I am new to regex, I am not familiar with the terms but I am trying to learn as soon as possible. Thanks a lot for your time and help so far.

Comment: Hi ,I can't accept this as an answer as it does not produce the desired output. The output it produces is "| Argentina Malbec | " whereas the desired output should be "Achaval Ferrer - Finca Mirador Mendoza 2005 South America 750ml". I hope you understand :( .

Comment: @RahulLahiri:- I am really not sure what you are upto and what you are looking for. Anyways good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use a regex in that way rather than just removing the pipes? E.g.

```
str.replace(/\|/g, "")
```

Comment: Of course I could do that and it will work. However, I am trying to develop an understanding of regex.